# Replacing a pattern using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to replace all the patterns
`s#_coded_block[#]` with `s#_coded_block_#` in myfile. I looked online on how to replace patterns with groupings and my command is:

```
sed -i -E 's/s\([0-9]*\)_coded_block\[\([0-9]*\)\]/s\1_coded_block_\2/g' myfile
```

However, I am getting

> invalid reference \2 on `s'

command's RHS when I execute this command.

Comment: would you provide sample data on which you want replacement is needed to be done ?

Comment: Remove -E and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `-E` option, you don't need backslashes before the capturing parentheses:

```
sed -i -E 's/s([0-9]*)_coded_block\[([0-9]*)\]/s\1_coded_block_\2/g' myfile
```

You might want one-or-more digits, in which case you use `+` instead of `*`. If you decide to drop the `-E`, your original code should work, though if you want at least one digit, you need to write `\{1,\}`:

```
sed -i 's/s\([0-9]\{1,\}\)_coded_block\[\([0-9]\{1,\}\)\]/s\1_coded_block_\2/g' myfile
```

The `-i` notation shown only works reliably with GNU `sed`.  BSD (macOS or Mac OS X) `sed` would treat the `-E` in the first command line as the suffix (in the second, you'd get a complaint about `m` not being a valid `sed` command because the script would be treated as the suffix and the `m` of `myfile` would be an erroneous `sed` command.  You'd use `-i ''` to back up (overwrite) a file with no suffix.  If you want portable code, use `-i.bak` which creates a backup file with both variants — the `.bak` must be attached to the `-i` for GNU `sed`.